# Unable to create correct batches using tf.train.batch()

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I have bunch of data with length of 5000 (though even inner list has different length) and type as numpy array:

```
In [39]: data.train_x
Out[39]: 
array([ [10, 2093, 121, 87451, 1, 10, 478, 4, 185, 4, 109, 239, 1527, 96, 16, -1, 116, 1, 33, 276, 56, 989, 12, 13, 1232, 2683, 12, 7166, 1],
       [-1, -1, -1, 43, 15, 626, 53, 524, 14, -1, 733, 1, 10, 68, 33, 1],
       [845, 14, -1, 32, 6455, 16, 29, 13987, 148, 4, 8995, 16, 1556, 1, 88, 610],
       ...,
       [151, 68, 353, 32, 46, -1, -1, 4, 29, 1034, 4, 15, 171, 122, 434, -1],
       [13182, 14732, 50100, 2917, 3526, 37, 48, 8617, 5057, 48, 2, 32029, 1477, 2, 5687, 5472, -1, 4, 127, 215, 425, 61376, -1],
       [13, 607, -1, 2476, 35, 171, 39, 515, -1, 3307, 2, 7094, 615, 92, -1, 4457, 46, 16, 26034, 13, 685, 2365, 543, -1]], dtype=object)
```

Then I have converted and created a list of tensors which each tensor represents one example of the original data:

```
inputs = [tf.convert_to_tensor(input, dtype=tf.int16) for input in data.train_x]
```

Now I have tried using both tf.train.batch() and tf.train.batch_join() to generate batched data:

```
batched_inputs = tf.train.batch(
    tensors=inputs,
    batch_size=50,
    dynamic_pad=True,
    # enqueue_many=True,
    name='batching'
)
```

The resulting batched data is wrong, and it simply creates a list (with the same length as `inputs`) of tensors and each tensor has a shape of (50, *length of one input*) I suspect it is just 50 replications of that input..

```
In [42]: batched_inputs[0]
Out[42]: <tf.Tensor 'batching_7:0' shape=(50, 29) dtype=int16>
```

Can someone please enlighten me on how to create correct batched data with the correct length and each batch is dynamically padded.

Thanks so much!!

**Update:**
Having read [LINK](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4022), it seems the issue is it tries `tf.pack()` the tensors which fails because they don't have the same length.. Tried a few things but haven't been successful.